# You (just now) not commited yet のコメントを消したい

Tags: sublimetext

packageやyarnでいろいろいじっていたせいなのかsublime textで　”You (just now)  not commited yet”　の警告？情報？がでるようになってしまいました。
入れたパッケージを消してみたりできることをやり尽くし燃え尽きました。
消し方知っている方いましたら教えていただけたらとても嬉しいです...

[image]

Comment: 解決しました！　gitgutterの設定を変更したらうまくいきました

Comment: 解決方法は「回答」として投稿していただけませんか? (自己回答の場合、承認できるようになるまで時間が必要ですが、「承認」もお願いします。)承認された回答があることで、同じことで悩む方々がこのスレッドを見つけやすくなります。

Answer (score 4):

GitGutter Settings - User に下記を追加することでメッセージ行の表示を消すことができます。

```
{
    "show_line_annotation": "false"
}
```